# Firebase Showing An Internal Error has occured. [7:]

Tags: java, android, firebase

I'm using Firebase as my cloud data in my android app. I'm using it's Firestore and Authentication feature. But when I try to signup it is showing me :

> "An internal error has occurred. [7:]"

So, to solve this I came to search for the solution so I found that if I update the `google_service.json` file everything is going to be right. But When I updated it sometimes it is working and after some time it again shows me the same error.

Comment: Share the logcat

Comment: make sure to have enabled the sign in method in your firebase console

Comment: The sign in method is enabled. And when I update the file it is working for some time but stops again after sometime

Comment: Did you enabled authentication method in the console Firebase?@Ashmit Pathak

Comment: cab you post the full stack trace?

Answer (score 6):

I get this error while testing my app behavior when deliberately disabling my mobile internet connection and trying to login to my app using firebase Auth.

Try testing your network connectivity on Activity launch and display a toast

```
public static boolean getConnectivityStatus(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (null != activeNetwork) {
            if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI)

                return true;

            if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE)
                return true;
        }
        Toast.makeText(context, "No network connection!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Internet issues was the problem I was having when getting this error.
Very weird that firebase is sending this incomplete error message.

Comment: I just want to point out that among Google's status codes there exists the following one: `CommonStatusCodes.NETWORK_ERROR = 7;`. In Google Sign-In, they extend `CommonStatusCodes` with additional ones via `GoogleSignInStatusCodes`, so that `CommonStatusCodes.NETWORK_ERROR` is reused when a GSI is attempted on a disconnected device. I really don't know why `FirebaseAuth` just sluggishly labels it as an internal error, making it hard for us to notify the users of the actual underlying error, instead of giving us a clean way to access the GSI status code.

Answer (score 2):

Please check the internet connection of your device.  I make the same mistake after internet connection enables it working.

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem with authentication via Firebase in my RN iOS project. After some research I found out that "Email/Password" Sign In/Up option was disabled. So I just turned it on. Hope it will help someone with similar issue.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zoQ6g.png

Answer (score 1):

Same error happened while I tried with network connection off and firebase authentication with email and password. for example,

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)... { ... }
```

If network connection is on, then it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

make sure you run your emulator like this in vs Code

flutter emulators --launch Nexus_6_API_29 -dns-8.8.8.8
this will solve your problem